# Problem installing QtOctave

Tags: software-installation, qt, matlab, octave

First I installed MATLAB and I got stuck here:

```
No MATLAB executables were found in the directories you specified.
This package requires at least one local installation of MATLAB.
```

I was unable to know what actually are the MATLAB executables.
Secondly I installed QtOctave as an alternative to MATLAB, but again the same error mentioned above appeared.

I also tried some answers from this site, but I was unable to install it.

Comment: Could you please add the result of `sudo apt-get install qtoctave`?

Comment: @SylvainPineau                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 matlab-support
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to fix the broken installation of MATLAB:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat 
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a
```

Alternatively you can remove matlab-support since you now want to install qtoctave:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove matlab-support
```

Finally re-run the qtoctave installation:

```
sudo apt-get install qtoctave
```

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: Close all package managers like the software center,synaptic or gdebi before running this command